# Translate text in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, translate

I'm using WPML  plugin to make my website multilingual and some of the text / button text can't be translate.

I have this code:

```
<div class="header-left">
    <div class="num">
        <strong>  Call us Now </strong>
        <a href="tel:0000000"> +000000 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this block of code in wordpress php file.

How to add this as a string so i can translate it with WPML?

Comment: I use QTranslate-X

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the text in a function like this :

```
<?php echo __('Call us Now', 'yourtextdomain'; ?>
```

or you can just do

```
<?php _e('Call us Now', 'yourtextdomain'; ?>
```

Then go to WPML and resync your theme or plugin where you have this text. (There is also an option to do that automatically)

Check the doc to know more :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: so this should be the result ?
--------------------------------------------------
<div class="header-left">
<div class="num"><strong><?php echo __('Call us Now', 'yourtextdomain'; ?></strong>
<a href="tel:0000">0000</a>
</div>
 </div>

Comment: Exactly like that. Juste replace yourtextdomain by what you want so  you can find it easily in wpml translation.